# HTML5 canvas source-atop alternative in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I cannot find the right function to add color overlay on another image when transparent areas should remain untouched.

For example on source image there is a semi-transparent white circle and around it everything is fully transparent. When I apply the operation with red color, I'd like to get white/red circle with fully transparent area around it.

On HTML5 canvas, it is achieved by:

```
layerContext.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
layerContext.fillStyle = color;
layerContext.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

I tried `alpha_composite`, `blend` and `composite` functions, but maybe misused them.

EDIT: here is what I get using:

```
overlay = Image.new('RGB', im1.size, (255, 0, 0))
im1.paste(overlay, mask=im1)
```

Canvas: [image: Canvas result]
PIL: [image: PIL result]

PIL result is a little bit lighter, but color is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTML5 Canvas, and documentation didn't help much. I think the method you are looking for is [`paste`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#image-paste-method). Some sample images would help to clarify the intended output.

Comment: @memoselyk, I've added sample images, using paste, here is a little color difference